# Is there is any way to call a function when an infinite loop or browsser hangs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging

hi i m working a project which have huge javascript code sometimes javascript code executes automaticaly and hangs browser with message "kill this page" in chrome is there is any way to track the error .like calling calling a function when infinite loop arrives or browsser hangs like that .please give me some suggestion about debugging javascript code plz.

Comment: Not that i know of. Maybe there might be a way using browser extensions.

Comment: When javascript hangs ur browser it eats up so much memory that the browser detects it and kills it.  You won't be able to run any more javascript to check it...

Comment: You may use timeout for suspected javascript methods.

Comment: thanx to all.. but jeschafe r u saying kill page is showing because of the browser eat so much memory ??? ... if yes then any way to check the useage of memory and clear the memory for regural inter val..

Comment: It does not need to much memory but modern browsers are using mechanisms to detect javascript problems like infinite loops. As I know they are base on time a function takes to execute. If it takes to long, the browser asks to skip the script. See the answers below how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing what you wish inside javascript.

However you can use a tool like [DynaTrace Ajax Edition](http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/dynatrace-ajax-download.html) to trace cpu usage in the browser to identify what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop can be caused in many different bad programming logic, and there is no reliable logic to detect in every case.  So I highly doubt if any programming language or IDE would offer any reliable infinite loop detection.

What you saw was basically a runtime detection based on how long script execution has taken before the browser could update and refresh the UI.

Sometimes this kind of long running JavaScript could be caused by infinite loop, but many times they are just big loops or loops that perform too much work that makes UI unresponsive.

Because JavaScript is not multi-thread, therefore to avoid the later case above, you could consider breaking the loops into small units of work, once a unit is finished, don't run the next unit, but instead call the next unit of work with    setTimeout with a small time delay (such as 250ms).  This would give the browser a chance to breath and update UI, and unmark your script as "long-running" script.

You may also use logging such as [Firebug Logging](http://getfirebug.com/logging/) to log the loops with enough values that help you find out if those loops are indeed infinite loops.